# Converting Varchar dataType to DateTime datatype using SSIS

Tags: ssis

I Have a table with the column name as [Time] and Data type is Varchar(50), i want to join this table with another table where i have a similar column with name Interval and Data type is DateTime.

I am not able to join these two tables as the data type for both the columns are different. 
SSIS it always gives me a conversion error.

I mam very new to this and clueless as what can be done.

Can some one please help me on this.

Comment: When i try to join this in SQl, getting an error Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend converting from DateTime to Varchar if all you want is to join the tables. This would be easier than converting Varchar to DateTime as you don't need to take the regional setting into account.

have fun!

Comment: Thanks  for helping out, will try this and come back to you.

Answer (score 0):

your dataflow shoud look like this (assuming both tables are sorted by time/interval):

[image]

Comment: I am sorry, but didn't understand by what u want to say. Can u please help me out by explaning the Above, I have not tried Merge yet, But let me try and getback to you.

Comment: As you said you are joining the tables I assumed you were using merge join. How does your data flow look like? could you please post a picture or explain its components?